# Android - Call Main Class Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to go back to the Main Activity at a certain point in my application. I tried calling the Activity in an Intent as usual, however since the Activity name for the main class is called "android.intent.action.MAIN", which is the general name of every application's main activity, a "Complete Action Using:" menu pops up with every possible application on the phone as an option. I do not want this; what I want is that the main activity for my application loads up.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also specify a specific `Activity` to launch like so:

```
Intent nextActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(nextActivityIntent);
```

As per the [Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), the [`ACTION_MAIN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN) flag is used to specify that you want to launch an application using the application's main entry point. You generally do not use it in your app unless you are trying to open another app.